# Vuetify v-select dose not load Css default style

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

[image]

I have added vuetify plugin the other components work well but when I added v-select on my custom components it did not load default Css shows like up pic

```
<v-select :items="items" label="Standard"></v-select>

data() {
return {
  items: [
    { title: "Click Me" },
    { title: "Click Me" },
    { title: "Click Me" },
    { title: "Click Me 2" },
  ],
};
```

},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of v-select I have used v-menu it work it but not as a v-select

```
<v-menu offset-y>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-btn
          color="primary"
          class="rounded-xl text-capitalize ps-3 pe-2"
          v-bind="attrs"
          v-on="on"
          outlined
          min-width="120px"
        >
          {{ selected_filter }}
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-icon>mdi-chevron-down</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </template>
      <v-list>
        <v-list-item v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
          <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-menu>

data() {
return {
  items: [
    { title: "Click Me" },
    { title: "Click Me" },
    { title: "Click Me" },
    { title: "Click Me 2" },
  ],
  selected_filter: "Today",
};
```

},